# C#: Dynamically convert primitive to Nullable<>

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm using reflection to iterate through the properties of objects. For `Nullable<>` types, the type is being returned correctly using the `PropertyType` property. However, when I invoke the property getter (either via `PropertyType.GetGetMethod().Invoke(obj, new object[0])` or `PropertyType.GetValue(obj, null)`, the result's type is the unwrapped primitive, not `Nullable<>`. For reason's I'd rather not go into, I need to convert this result into its `Nullable<>` type. This throws an `InvalidCastException` in such cases:

```
Convert.ChangeType(property.GetValue(obj, null), property.PropertyType);
```

Is there another way to ensure the property value's type is always the same as the property's type?

Comment: " For reason's I'd rather not go into" - entirely up to you, of course, but what you ask for **cannot exist** - perhaps if you could add some context (change the names if you like - we won't know or care), we might be able to suggest a better option.

Comment: If you really must know, I'm porting an XML encoder from Java to C#. I'm not replacing one with the other - both will exist and be maintained, so I'm trying to minimise their divergence from each other. I have an `IDictionary<Type,IConverter>` (`IConverter` is mine) which acts as a registry of property types to attribute value converters. Because of this issue I have, it's breaking for `Nullable`s.

Comment: I would write a brief bit of code after the initial registrations that uses `MakeGenericType` to double all the registrations - i.e. for each `type`, adds the same converter against `typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(type)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do that in reflection code, because in reflection code you are talking about `object`, and there **is no such thing** as a boxed `Nullable<T>` - it is either the boxed underlying value, or a `null`.

If you know the actual type, you can use the constructor to create a wrapped value, but it **must** only be assigned to a typed field/variable that is `Nullable<T>` - not `object` - else the CLI unwraps it again.

However, for that same reason, you **don't need** it wrapped when using reflection; any code like `SetValue` will accept `object`, and will do the right thing; regardless of whether it is `null` or a boxed underlying value, it will be handled correctly.

Basically, the CLI has special handling when boxing and unboxing `Nullable<T>` that makes the question void.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still have a bit to learn about boxing in C#. Since I need the type as an `IDictionary<>` key and I know all my primitives are wrapped in `Nullable<>`, I have changed the design a bit to create a type using `(obj.GetType().IsValueType ? typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(new[]{obj.GetType()}) : obj.GetType())` as the key. It works now.

Comment: @SteveTaylor note that *that level* of reflection (`MakeGenericType` etc) is pretty slow; fine for moderate use, but if this is a tight loop you *might* want to optimise that a bit...

Comment: Thanks for the tip. dotTrace is my friend. :)